# How can I get previous Date from Timer publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to simplify this code

```
var sampleTimer:AnyCancellable?
var lastSampleUpdate:Date!

func startSampling(on date:Date) {
    lastSampleUpdate = date
    sampleTimer = Timer.publish(every: 20, on: .main, in: .default)
        .autoconnect()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink(receiveValue: newDate(endDate:))
}

func newDate(endDate:Date)  {
    let timeDifference = endDate - lastSampleUpdate
    print("\(timeDifference) seconds passed")
    lastSampleUpdate = endDate
}
```

I am sure this is common, but I also know that CurrentvalueSubject provides a previous value without storing it explicitly. How would I alter this to lose the lastSampleUpdate variable?

Comment: There is an operator for this purpose: [Scan](https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsscan.html)

Comment: Great resource, thanks.